# How to use methods on arrays in an object

Tags: javascript, object

```js
myObj = {anArray: ["1", "2", "3", "4"]}

if (myObj["anArray"].includes("2")) {
    console.log("hey")
}
```

this throws an error:

```
TypeError: MyObject.anArray.contains is not a function
```

So how do I use methods on an array in an object?
any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Arrays don't (or shouldn't) have a `.contains()` method, they have [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: @VLAZ sorry I meant `.includes()`

Comment: In that case, your code works.

Answer (score 2):

`contains()` doesn't exist for Array in javascript.

Have a look on `includes()` which return `true` or `false`, or `indexOf()` which return the position.

[W3School - includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp)

[W3School - indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Array has no method `contains` use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead

```js
const myObj = { anArray: ['1', '2', '3', '4'] };

if (myObj['anArray'].includes('2')) {
    console.log('hey');
}
```